# Set variations default attributes values for a variable product Programmatically

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, product-variations

I'm building a site where WooCommerce Variable products (with Products Variations) are inserted programmatically. I have followed this tutorial successfully: 
[Insert WooCommerce Products & Variations Programmatically](http://ryanknights.co.uk/insert-woocommerce-products-variations-programmatically/)

I need just something that is missing: 
How to set variations default attributes values for a variable product?
Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1). You will need to insert in your **`json`** data for each variable product this piece of array like:

```
        "variations_default_attributes":
        [
            {
                "size"  : "Medium",
                 "color" : "Blue"
            }
        ]
```

Or

```
    "variations_default_attributes":
    {
        "size"  : "Medium",
        "color" : "Blue"
    }
```

*This array is made with the attribute short slug (without '**`pa_`**') and the default term **name** values.*

2). Then the dedicated function:

```
function insert_variations_default_attributes( $post_id, $products_data ){
    foreach( $products_data as $attribute => $value )
        $variations_default_attributes['pa_'.$attribute] = get_term_by( 'name', $value, 'pa_'.$attribute )->slug;
    // Save the variation default attributes to variable product meta data
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_default_attributes', $variations_default_attributes );
}
```

3). You will need to trigger this function adding one line at the end:

```
function insert_product ($product_data)  
{
    $post = array( // Set up the basic post data to insert for our product

        'post_author'  => 1,
        'post_content' => $product_data['description'],
        'post_status'  => 'publish',
        'post_title'   => $product_data['name'],
        'post_parent'  => '',
        'post_type'    => 'product'
    );

    $post_id = wp_insert_post($post); // Insert the post returning the new post id

    if (!$post_id) // If there is no post id something has gone wrong so don't proceed
    {
        return false;
    }

    update_post_meta($post_id, '_sku', $product_data['sku']); // Set its SKU
    update_post_meta( $post_id,'_visibility','visible'); // Set the product to visible, if not it won't show on the front end

    wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $product_data['categories'], 'product_cat'); // Set up its categories
    wp_set_object_terms($post_id, 'variable', 'product_type'); // Set it to a variable product type

    insert_product_attributes($post_id, $product_data['available_attributes'], $product_data['variations']); // Add attributes passing the new post id, attributes & variations
    insert_product_variations($post_id, $product_data['variations']); // Insert variations passing the new post id & variations

    ## Insert variations default attributes passing the new post id & variations_default_attributes
    insert_variations_default_attributes( $post_id, $products_data['variations_default_attributes'] );    
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works.

Comment: Tried update_post_meta( $post_id, '_default_attributes', $variations_default_attributes ); in wc3.0 this doesn't work. So I tried the following: $standardValArr = array(); $standardValArr['pa_groesse'] = 'M'; $parent_product->set_default_attributes($standardValArr); Unfortunately this doesn't work.

Comment: @JanineKroser What are you trying to do? what is the problem or your problem? May be you should ask a new question, as this answer might not be convenient for you.